# JS HTML CSS Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm looking to use this code I have modified for larger chunks of information. It appears that the text is cut off without any padding. Any advice on how to fix it?

Here is my code. You can see where the images on the accordions end and the text collides into them.

```
    .container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    }
```

```js
//uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };
  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  //function
  switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
  };
  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.heading-primary {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.accordion dl,
.accordion-list {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.accordion dl:after,
.accordion-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #026453;
}
.accordion dd,
.accordion__panel {
  /*text background */
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.accordion p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/1.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  height: 83px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bc812A;
}
/* ACCORDION 2 */

#accordion__Heading2 {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/2.jpg);
}
#accordion__Heading3 {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/3.jpg);
}
/*ACCORDION 3 */

/*
.accordion__Heading2 {
  background-color: #363636;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #30bb64;
}

.accordion__Heading3 {
  background-color: #121212;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #30bb64;
} 

*/

.accordionTitle:before,
.accordion__Heading:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover,
.accordion__Heading:hover {
  background-color: #006554;
}
.accordionTitleActive,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded {
  background-color: #000;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 15em;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}
.accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}
.no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: auto;
}
.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
}
.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading-primary">SSC On-Boarding Accordions</h1>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger"> <!--First Accordion heading-->  </a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" id="accordion__Heading2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                  <!-- Second Accordion heading--></a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum.
          Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion3" id="accordion__Heading3" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                    <!--Third Accordion heading-->
                </a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion3" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum.
          Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rujsyemg/) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cutting off because you have a combination of `overflow:hidden` and `max-height:15em` on your `.accordionItem` class. In order for the content to show entirely, you need to get rid of the `max-height:15em` declaration.

```js
//uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };
  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  //function
  switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
  };
  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.heading-primary {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.accordion dl,
.accordion-list {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.accordion dl:after,
.accordion-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #026453;
}
.accordion dd,
.accordion__panel {
  /*text background */
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.accordion p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/1.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  height: 83px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bc812A;
}
/* ACCORDION 2 */

#accordion__Heading2 {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/2.jpg);
}
#accordion__Heading3 {
  background-image: url(960%20accordions/3.jpg);
}
/*ACCORDION 3 */

/*
.accordion__Heading2 {
  background-color: #363636;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #30bb64;
}

.accordion__Heading3 {
  background-color: #121212;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #30bb64;
} 

*/

.accordionTitle:before,
.accordion__Heading:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover,
.accordion__Heading:hover {
  background-color: #006554;
}
.accordionTitleActive,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded {
  background-color: #000;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
   /* max-height: 15em;*/
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}
.accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}
.no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: auto;
}
.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
}
.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading-primary">SSC On-Boarding Accordions</h1>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger"> <!--First Accordion heading-->  </a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" id="accordion__Heading2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                  <!-- Second Accordion heading--></a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum.
          Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion3" id="accordion__Heading3" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                    <!--Third Accordion heading-->
                </a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion3" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum.
          Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```